# Launch guest profile programmatically android

Tags: android, android-5.0-lollipop

In Lollipop Android now has support for multiple user accounts.  I'm referring to the the user accounts that can be switched between from the notification shade.  Is it possible to programmatically launch guest mode?  Or the user account picker?

Comment: Did you figure out if this can b achieved ?